# Getting Bad Request from API Post Call using Retrofit

Tags: java, android, post, retrofit2

I have created the next savePartner() method inside PartnerController class like this:

```
 public void savePartner(View partnerForm) {
        context = partnerForm.getContext();

        PartnerDto partner = createPartner(partnerForm);
        
        String jsonPartner = convert(partner);

        Call<String> call = appAPI.savePartner("application/json", jsonPartner);

        Log.i(TAG, "getPartners submitted to API.");

        call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    String responseCall = response.body();

                } else {
                    System.out.println(response.errorBody());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                TableRow rowHeader = new TableRow(context);

                TextView name = new TextView(context);
                name.setText(t.getMessage());

                rowHeader.addView(name);

                //partnerForm.addView(rowHeader);

                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
```

And I have added the method savePartner to retrofit interface:

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Header;
import retrofit2.http.Headers;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface IApplicationApi {
    @GET("Partner/")
    //Call<List<PartnerDto>> loadPartners(@Header("Authorization") String authorization);
    Call<List<PartnerDto>> loadPartners();

    @POST("Partner/")
    Call<String> savePartner(@Header("Content-Type") String content_type, @Body String partner);
}
```

When I execute the post call in postman works (code 200), but I debugged the previous in android-studio and I obtain the next error:

> Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=Bad Request, url=https://localhost/Partner/}

[image: Error]

And I can't obtain more info about the error. The request is the next:

> Request{method=POST, url=https://localhost/Partner/, tags={class retrofit2.Invocation=administracion.MyProject.APIService.IApplicationApi.savePartner() [application/json, {"email":null,"id":4,"lastname":null,"name":"me","phonenumber":0,"productamount":0.0,"productquantity":0.0,"registereddate":"2021-02-10T00:00:00"}]}}

I put these values on postman, and it works like a charm. I don't know why this request is bad. Could someone give me some clue?

Thanks in advance for the help! ^^

**Updated 01/03/2021**

I can get the cause of the error using httplogginginterceptor, I share this in case someone more need it :)

https://howtodoinjava.com/retrofit2/logging-with-retrofit2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use HttpLoggingInterceptor and log your request. I hope you are missing a field in your json body or request body

Comment: How can I use it? Could you share some documentation links or examples?

Comment: I have achieved the reason of the fail using this and in my log now tells me the reason of the failed post :)!! Thank you so much! ^^  I used this example https://howtodoinjava.com/retrofit2/logging-with-retrofit2/

Answer (score 0):

try  replacing this @POST("Partner/")
with @POST("Partner")